# Up-to-date Matrix Cookbook

Tags: matrices, reference-request, online-resources, reference-works

My copy of the Matrix cookbook is dated November 15, 2012, and is the newest copy I've been able to find.

Identities may not change overtime, but the approach to an error-free presentation can be asymptotic, and some topics may be missing. Where can I find an up-to-date copy?

The address "matrixcookbook.com" listed in the 2012 book is defunct, the email in the book doesn't work, and the 2302.dk website seems to be out of commission, and I haven't found personal sites for the authors.

Comment: That is the latest version I could find too. Maybe it's time for a new collaborative cookbook.

Comment: @qwr: See my answer below: https://github.com/r-barnes/MatrixForensics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm making good progress---360 equations---on compiling a matrix mathematics reference *Matrix Forensics* [here](https://github.com/r-barnes/MatrixForensics). Crucially, the LaTeX source is available so that others can contribute and add to it over time.

The compiled PDF is available here: https://github.com/r-barnes/MatrixForensics/raw/master/matrix_forensics.pdf

Comment: Looks good. What's the story behind the name?

Comment: I'm not beholden to the name, but the idea came up when we were trying to track down a particular matrix identity: performing forensics on the available evidence.

Comment: The name doesn't really make sense to me. Cookbook or handbook or reference makes more sense.

Comment: @qwr: Thanks for your feedback here. It might make more sense to open this as a Github issue. "Cookbook" is nice, but already used, as it were.

Comment: Sure, I can contribute on github, although I'm not that good at matrix stuff

Comment: @Richard I think equation (43) in the reference is missing an $\epsilon$.